# Why do i have multiple google-domains (.com, .de, ...) as sources of traffic

Tags: google-analytics

In my google-analytics account on the `Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Source/Medium` - View i see multiple google websites as source.

In the screenshot below you can see 3 times google/organic (3., 4. and 7.)
and 2 times google/cpc (5. and 6.)

Do you know why is this happening and (even more important) how can i fix it?

This is my custom Trackingcode:

```
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-*', 'my-domain.com', {
    'siteSpeedSampleRate': 10,
    'sampleRate': 100
});
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
setTimeout('ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'NoBounce\', \'Over defined seconds\')', 10000);
ga('send', 'pageview');
var perfData = window.performance.timing;
var pageLoadTime = perfData.domComplete - perfData.navigationStart;
var loadTime = "";
if (pageLoadTime < 1000) {
    loadTime = "0-1 seconds";
} else if (pageLoadTime < 2000) {
    loadTime = "1-2 seconds";
} else if (pageLoadTime < 3000) {
    loadTime = "2-3 seconds";
} else if (pageLoadTime < 4000) {
    loadTime = "3-4 seconds";
} else if (pageLoadTime < 5000) {
    loadTime = "4-5 seconds";
} else if (pageLoadTime < 6000) {
    loadTime = "5-6 seconds";
} else if (pageLoadTime < 10000) {
    loadTime = "6-10 seconds";
} else {
    loadTime = "10+ seconds";
}
ga('set', 'metric1', loadTime);
```

[image]

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your comment. I just added my custom tracking-code. I am not sure if it is a option-related problem or one with my trackingcode. If its a trackingcode-issue i guess it belongs here...

Comment: No idea. I removed my close vote.   I am running though the accounts I have access to none of them have that.   weird.....

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange about that report. You are looking at source and medium together which is why google.de shows up multiple times with different mediums (media?). Organic is different from cpc (paid ads).

The last little detail about the two `google.de / organic` ones is that one has a trailing `/` after the domain and one doesn't. That would be the only thing that can be 'fixed'. The way you can do that is by adding a custom filter to the view in Google Analytics that replaces the trailing slash with nothing. It will look something like this:

[image: Source Rewrite]

The filter uses a regular expression, so to remove a forward slash at the end of a string simply escape the forward slash and add a `$` to denote the end of a string. Google uses `https` by default but in case you find http vs https splitting your data you can add another filter removing `^https?:\/\/(www)?` with nothing as well to remove the protocol and `www` if it exists.